# remove git file from repository not having local copy

Tags: git, bitbucket

working with git is obvious when u have local copy of repository on disk but sometimes there is requirement to work only with specific file(s) from known address of repository.

So here it is: my target is to delete single file or known list of file in given repo - the hard part is that because of performance reasons i don't want to clone entire repository to disk. I'm using already bitbucket server api but it seems there is no way of doing it. Of course i want to be able to see this operation later in git as a commit.

Comment: You can shallow clone a repo, but you _will_ need to clone at least one commit.

Comment: Doesn't the BitBucket API allow this? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-commit-file-to-Bitbucket-using-API/qaq-p/276435

Comment: i'm talking about this api: https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.8.2/bitbucket-rest.html which looks like it doesn't support delete file from repo

Answer (score 1):

All git mutable operations can only work on a *working tree*. So if you want to do a commit it needs to be applied to a working tree. Whether this one resides on your local machine or somewhere else is equal. But the git executable needs *file system access* to it. You won't come around this restriction. Even git commands that seem manipulate the repository directly (like --filter-branch) use a temporary working tree.

But you can **speed up** things when you use a **shallow clone** (`--depth 1`) rather than a full clone. This *significantly faster*.

Note that you need a sufficiently recent git version for this to work. See also here: [Better support for shallow clones in git 1.9](https://blog.oio.de/2014/02/06/better-support-for-shallow-clones-in-git-1-9/)

---

Another option is to create a service at the repository server that does the job for you. This is faster because the main traffic is now *local*.
But of course using a third party git server like butbucket this is not an option.

Comment: What’s a mutable operation in git?

Comment: The opposite of an immutable operation. Take a look at [this oxford entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mutable)

Comment: *All git mutable operations can only work on a working tree.* I doubt that this is true. You may want to take a look at the [Plumbing and Porcelain section](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) of the git book. This works on bare repos.

Comment: so the flow could look like this: (1) shallow clone repo to local folder (2) delete file from local repo folder (3) make commit back to repo ?